# Should I know Java Concurrency & Thread Model etc. Comprehensively Before Using Concurrency in Clojure?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, clojure, lisp

I don't know much about concurrency in Java such as Fork/Join Framework, Locks, Threads(comprehensively), Executors etc.

I just have little basic knowledge & theoretical about it.

Since Clojure runs on JVM, I thought that I must know Java's concurrency model really well before jump into Clojure(concurrency)?

I write Java but never needed concurrency at work.

Now I write Clojure and want to do some concurrency/parallelism stuff with it.

Should I know Java's Concurrency model or Can I learn while practicing with Clojure?

Comment: You need to understand the hardware before you touch concurrency.

Comment: I disagree! That is a very deceptive statement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't nead to learn such things to use Clojure's concurrency and parallelism features.

I'm never going to advocate not learning something, though in this case if you are learning these things at the same time you may be tempted to reach for locks in Clojure, which is almost always unnecessary, rather then doing it the idiomatic Clojure way.

What you certainly do need to learn is the fundamental ideas of concurrent programming and parallel programming. Things like how to intelligently split work, and how to combine the results so you get correct answers.

Also how to avoid crating so many threads that you cause resource starvation. These things can be learned in (almost) any language, though learning them in Clojure is more fun than some others.

One possible danger is that when working without the Clojure features you may find less satisfaction when going back to the more traditional OO approach in Java.